# Having difficulty pulling data from oracle database to javabean and jsp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

I have a javabean name FanBean which has this function below that pulls the data from the oracle database

```
 public java.util.Vector getList() {

        java.util.Vector myFanList = new java.util.Vector();
        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();

        DbUtil db = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;

            db = new DbUtil();

            sql.append(" SELECT id_no, name");
                if ((this.getSelectedFanType() != null)&& (this.getSelectedFanType().equals("1"))){
                    sql.append("  from my_fan ");
                }

                if ((this.getSelectedFanType() != null)&& (this.getSelectedFanType().equals("2"))){
                    sql.append("  from my_fan ");
                    sql.append("  where id_no = '");
                    sql.append(this.getSearchVar());
                    sql.append("'");
                }

                if ((this.getSelectedFanType() != null)&& (this.getSelectedFanType().equals("3"))){
                    sql.append("  from my_fan ");
                    sql.append("  where name = '");
                    sql.append(this.getSearchVar());
                    sql.append("'");
                }



            if (this.getSelectedSort() != null) {
                if(this.getSelectedSort().equals("1"))
                    sql.append(" ORDER BY id_no");
                else if(this.getSelectedSort().equals("2"))
                    sql.append(" ORDER BY name");
                else
                    sql.append(" ORDER BY id_no");
            } else
                sql.append(" ORDER BY id_no");

            rset =  db.executeQuery(sql.toString(),true);

            if (rset != null) {
                while(rset.next()) {
                    FanBean myFan = new FanBean();
                    myFan.setIdNo(rset.getString(1).trim());
                    myFan.setName(rset.getString(2));


                myFanList.addElement(myFan);
                Enumeration e = myFanList.elements();
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                FanBean nextFan = (FanBean) e.nextElement();
                this.addDtlItem(nextFan.getIdNo(), nextFan.getName());
                }
                }
            }

        }

    return myFanList;
    }
```

I have this function which adds the data to FanItemBean java bean

```
public void addDtlItem(String idNo, String name )
    {
        FanItemBean detailItem = new FanItemBean(idNo, name);
        _dtlListArray.add(detailItem);

    }
```

And finally in jsp I pull the data like this

```
 <%
    Collection dtlItems = fanBean.getDetailItems();
    Iterator it = dtlItems.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    String colorStr = null;


    while(it.hasNext()){
        FanItemBean fanDtlItem = (FanItemBean) it.next();

    %>

        <TR>
            <TD><%= fanDtlItem.getIdNo()%></TD>
            <TD><%= fanDtlItem.getName()%></TD>
        </TR>
<% 
  i++;
} %>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in this cycle, I am not getting any data in jsp page. Thank you

Comment: just checking, but are you sure your JSP works? It looks like in your script in the JSP you are missing a closing "}" for your while loop (assuming you copied this directly from your JSP I am sure that will cause an issue).

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to add it.. i have that..

Comment: Where do you add the beans to your request context? Do you use a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a lot of things wrong with this code.

1. Where is _`dltListArray` defined and initialized?
2. Your while loop for `rs.next()` seems to be incorrect. You are adding the element into a list and immediately iterating over the enumeration instead of waiting for the rest of the `while()` loop to finish. This is **correct** code.

   ```
     if (rset != null) {
           while(rset.next()) {
               FanBean myFan = new FanBean();
               myFan.setIdNo(rset.getString(1).trim());
               myFan.setName(rset.getString(2));


               myFanList.addElement(myFan);
          } // FINISH ADDING ALL RESULTS TO YOUR LIST BEFORE ITERATING OVER THE ENUMERATION

          Enumeration e = myFanList.elements();
          while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            FanBean nextFan = (FanBean) e.nextElement();
            this.addDtlItem(nextFan.getIdNo(), nextFan.getName());
          }
       }
   ```
3. Also, your FanBean and FanItemBean seem identical. Why not just add it directly to your list instead of going through an intermediate Vector?
4. Any specific restrictions against using Java 1.5 and generics?
5. Also, where in your jsp are you calling the `getList()` method?